# Nullpointer Exception when retrieving from database too cursor

Tags: android, database, cursor, nullpointerexception, sqliteopenhelper

EDIT 4: I have a game Im trying to use to save a highscore from. From the main menu the user presses a 'View Highscore' button which calls the ViewHighscores activity. From here the activity tries to display all current saved scores. It seems like it thinks the database is empty, and that its never reaching the onCreate, but I dont know why

```
package nick.android.com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class ViewHighscores extends ListActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private ArrayAdapter<String> myHighscoreAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> myHighscoreMessage = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Object> data = new ArrayList<Object>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.viewhighscores);

    myHighscoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myHighscoreMessage);

    setListAdapter(myHighscoreAdapter);

    retrieveHighscores();

}

public void retrieveHighscores() {

    DatabaseOpenHelper database = new DatabaseOpenHelper(this);

    Cursor cursor = database.getHighscore();

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

            data.add(cursor.getString(0));
            data.add(cursor.getString(1));

            displayHighscores();

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    } else {
        myHighscoreAdapter.add("No Highscores Recorded Yet");
    }

}

public void displayHighscores() {

    myHighscoreAdapter.add("Highscore: " + data);

}

public void returnToMenu(View view) {

    finish();
    Intent returnToMenuButton = new Intent(view.getContext(),
            MainMenu.class);
    startActivity(returnToMenuButton);
}

}
```

Here is the piece of code from the game itself that tries too write too the database. getUserName(); retrieves a userName from an editText and numberOfGuesses is a number between 1 and 12

```
public void saveHighscore() {

    scoreSaved = true;

    getUserName();

    DatabaseOpenHelper database = new DatabaseOpenHelper(this);

    database.addHighscore(userName, numberOfGuesses);

}
```

Here is the DatabaseOpenHelper class

```
package nick.android.com;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HIGHSCORE_DATABASE";
private static final String HIGHSCORE_TABLE = "highscore";
static final String col_HighscoreID = "_id";
static final String col_HighscoreUser = "highscoreuser";
static final String col_Highscore = "highscore";
private SQLiteDatabase db;

DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + HIGHSCORE_TABLE + " (" + col_HighscoreID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + col_HighscoreUser
            + " TEXT , " + col_Highscore + " INTEGER)");

    System.out.println("ITS GETTING HERE");

    inputComputerHighscores();

}

public void inputComputerHighscores() {

    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    try {

        value.put(col_HighscoreUser, "Gold");
        value.put(col_Highscore, "3");
        db.insert(HIGHSCORE_TABLE, null, value);

        long dbcheck = db.insert(HIGHSCORE_TABLE, null, value);
        System.out.println(dbcheck);

        value.put(col_HighscoreUser, "Silver");
        value.put(col_Highscore, "6");
        db.insert(HIGHSCORE_TABLE, null, value);

        value.put(col_HighscoreUser, "Bronze");
        value.put(col_Highscore, "9");
        db.insert(HIGHSCORE_TABLE, null, value);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    db.close();

}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public Cursor getHighscore() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = null;

    try {

        cursor = db.query(HIGHSCORE_TABLE, new String[] { col_HighscoreID,
                col_HighscoreUser, col_Highscore }, null, null, null, null,
                col_Highscore + " asc");

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("DB Retrieval Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    db.close();

    return cursor;

}


public void addHighscore(String Username, int Score) {

    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();

    value.put(col_HighscoreUser, Username);
    value.put(col_Highscore, Score);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    try {

        db.insert(HIGHSCORE_TABLE, null, value);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

}
```

And here is the Logcat if I open the ViewHighscores activity <<< CHANGED EDIT 5 - It now force closes again:

```
01-13 16:06:17.032: D/AndroidRuntime(444): Shutting down VM
01-13 16:06:17.032: W/dalvikvm(444): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nick.android.com/nick.android.com.ViewHighscores}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWritableDatabase called recursively
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWritableDatabase called recursively
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:101)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at nick.android.com.DatabaseOpenHelper.inputComputerHighscores(DatabaseOpenHelper.java:40)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at nick.android.com.DatabaseOpenHelper.onCreate(DatabaseOpenHelper.java:33)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:126)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at nick.android.com.DatabaseOpenHelper.getHighscore(DatabaseOpenHelper.java:78)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at nick.android.com.ViewHighscores.retrieveHighscores(ViewHighscores.java:39)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at nick.android.com.ViewHighscores.onCreate(ViewHighscores.java:31)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-13 16:06:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(444):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Which one is line 42 in ViewHighscores.java? That's where the NPE is occurring

Comment: Line 42 is the if(!(cursor == null)) {

Comment: Huh that's weird, are you sure the stack trace was obtained with this exact version of the code? haven't you modified it a bit since?

Comment: (By the way, you can rewrite it if (cursor != null), it looks nicer ;)

Comment: Only change I made was adding in the getReadableDatabase. The stacktrace was the same when I ran it again though =(

Comment: I just added an edit for more info if thats helpful

Comment: And you are not getting any errors there? db.insert returns the ID of the insert. assign the result to a variable and confirm that you are actually inserting something.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if (!(cursor == null)) {

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
```

To something like this and a while:

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {

    cursor.moveToFirst();

while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false){

//Do what you want


 cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

But according to your last edit, that might not be enough, since maybe you are not saving anything.

Comment: This did prevent it force closing whenever I tried to open the Activity so thank you for that. However, its always saying there is nothing in the cursor and just displays "No Highscores Recorded Yet" - So I guess the way Im setting up my database is wrong? I will edit in my changed code now

Comment: Then you have something wrong with your code that stores in the database. Can you access the database in the emulator? Please post the code where you store them.

Comment: Where you see the LogCat there is another tab that says Files, there you could access the data folder and then export your database to see if you are saving data. However, not always works. Anyway, it's better if you post the code where you save to your database. It appears its empty.

Comment: Im not sure where this Files thing is, cant find it, but I will add where I write too the database. As it shows already is does actually write too the database onCreate already but I'll put the other part in too

Comment: And you are not getting any errors there? db.insert returns the ID of the insert. assign the result to a variable and confirm that you are actually inserting something.

Comment: I am getting error yeah but it doesn't force close. The error I get is in Edit 1. I will try to check the insert thing now

Comment: I try putting System.out.println("ITS GETTING HERE") in the onCreate method and System.out.println(dbcheck) in the inputComputerHighscores (where dbcheck - long dbcheck = db.insert(HIGHSCORE_TABLE,null,value)) just after the same code should be used to insert the 'Gold' user into the database. Neither println appears in Logcat

Comment: Im going to quickly redit my original post with the code in its current state and the current Logcat message, 2 secs

Comment: Then you must be getting an exception. Please make sure you are seeing all the types of logs. You clearly have a problem with the insert. The thing is that your code now looks fine. Delete the data from your application. Maybe you created the database before and then you didnt have the _id column. If that doesnt work, we'll move this into a chat.

Comment: By delete the data do you drop all the tables? I did originally not have an _id column thats right.

Comment: I just tried to put in

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+HIGHSCORE_TABLE);
        
    onCreate(db);

too the start of my getHighscore(); method, and it gave me a massive error and force closed. Do you want too see the logCat?

Comment: No need. Go to manage applications, choose your application and press the button delete data or something like that. Then start your application again. The problem is that you didnt have the _id column before.

Comment: Mega fail question (as you can tell I suck with Eclipse)... where is Manage Applications

*--dont bite me--*

Comment: OOOOOOOH IDIOT!!!! I was looking in Eclipse. It was on the android emulator. HERP DERP

Comment: Okay, so I uninstalled and deleted all data, went to run it and got another error (I hate my life) - I will edit the LogCat in now. A chat would help. this is so long winded

Comment: I can't invite you to chat. Don't worry. You'll get it. Pass the database to your inputComputerHighscores(); instead of asking for a writeable database again. You are also missing some try and catch, but step by step.